# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo in Fragment using camera

Tags: java, android, exception, camera, fragment

I tried to run my code like following but I got an exception when I click capture button for the camera inside fragment.

My Project built on Navigation Drawer which take fragments and inside fragment `ChangeMeterForm`  I added another fragment `ServiceInfo` which contain details about customer.

But when I clicked capture button I got an exception in `serviceInfo` fragment. I tried a lot solutions but everytime I got the same error

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.replace_meter_form, container, false);
            try
            {
                context = getActivity();
                serviceItems = new ArrayList<ServiceObj>();

                // Ticket Session Manager
                session = new SessionManager(context);
                dbObject = new SQLiteDB(context);



                Ticket t_info = session.getTicketInfo();
                final String ticketSeqID = t_info.getSeqID();
                final int ticket_index_id = t_info.getId();
                final String serviceId = t_info.getServiceId();
                session.setTicketID(ticket_index_id);

                // get user ticket and employee id's
                final String system_user = t_info.getUserInput();
                final String empID = session.getEmployeeDetails().getEmpID();

                ListValueHandler handler = new ListValueHandler(context, dbObject);
                getServiceMeters task = new getServiceMeters();
                task.execute(serviceId);

                // get the service information frame
                    try
                    {
                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        params.putString("serviceId", session.getTicketInfo().getServiceId());
                        // initlize fragment object
                        serviceInfo serInfoFrag = new serviceInfo();
                        serInfoFrag.setArguments(params);
                        //calling manager
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        // excute and show fragment
                        transaction.add(R.id.serviceDetails_replaceMeter, serInfoFrag).commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }
        private Uri captureImage(String name)
            {
                try
                {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, name);
                    //Log.d("Directory ", fileUri.getPath());
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

                    // start the image capture Intent
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return fileUri;
            }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                // if the result is capturing Image

                //delete image if exist
                //insert new image
                IMAGE newImage = new IMAGE();
                    dbObject.deleteImage(session.getImageName(), session.getTicketInfo().getGroupType(),"1",session.getTicketInfo().getServiceId());

                    newImage.setServiceId(session.getTicketInfo().getServiceId());
                    newImage.setImageName(session.getImageName());
                    newImage.setImagePath(CONSTANTS.getImagePath(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, session.getTicketInfo().getGroupType()) + session.getImageName() + ".jpg");
                    newImage.setActionType("1");
                    newImage.setGroupType(session.getTicketInfo().getGroupType());



                    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
                        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                            Toast.makeText(context,"Image Captured ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            // successfully captured the image
                            // display it in image view
                            try
                            {
                                previewCapturedImage();

                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                            // user cancelled Image capture
                            Toast.makeText(context,context.getResources().getText(R.string.cancel_capture_camera_lbl),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // failed to capture image
                            Toast.makeText(context, context.getText(R.string.failed_capture_camera_lbl), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        dbObject.insertNewImage(newImage);



                    }
        }

private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Show Images",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String newMeterNo = newMeterID.getText().toString().trim();
            final String ticketIndex = session.getTicketInfo().getServiceId() + "_" + newMeterNo;

            String path1 = CONSTANTS.getImagePath("ReplacedMeters", session.getTicketInfo().getGroupType()) + ticketIndex + "_1.jpg";
            String path2 = CONSTANTS.getImagePath("ReplacedMeters", session.getTicketInfo().getGroupType()) + ticketIndex + "_2.jpg";
            String path3 = CONSTANTS.getImagePath("ReplacedMeters", session.getTicketInfo().getGroupType()) + ticketIndex + "_3.jpg";
            String path4 = CONSTANTS.getImagePath("ReplacedMeters", session.getTicketInfo().getGroupType()) + ticketIndex + "_4.jpg";
            String path5 = CONSTANTS.getImagePath("ReplacedMeters", session.getTicketInfo().getGroupType()) + ticketIndex + "_5.jpg";

            Toast.makeText(context,"Path 1  "+path1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;
            File pic = new File(path1);
            if (pic.exists()) {
                final Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path1,
                        options);
                imageButton1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
            }

            pic = new File(path2);
            if (pic.exists()) {
                final Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path2,
                        options);
                imageButton2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
            }

            pic = new File(path3);
            if (pic.exists()) {
                final Bitmap bitmap3 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path3,
                        options);
                imageButton3.setImageBitmap(bitmap3);
            }

            pic = new File(path5);
            if (pic.exists()) {
                final Bitmap bitmap5 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path5,
                        options);
                idImageBtn.setImageBitmap(bitmap5);
            }

            pic = new File(path4);
            if (pic.exists()) {
                final Bitmap bitmap5 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path4,
                        options);
                imageButton4.setImageBitmap(bitmap5);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

---

Exception

```
    STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cpm.jdeco.metersapp/com.jdeco.metersapp.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f0148 (cpm.jdeco.metersapp:id/serviceDetails_replaceMeter) for fragment serviceInfo{35c646f #3 id=0x7f0f0148}
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3133)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5180)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:218)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6914)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f0148 (cpm.jdeco.metersapp:id/serviceDetails_replaceMeter) for fragment serviceInfo{35c646f #3 id=0x7f0f0148}
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1264)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3096)
```

Comment: Please Do check your layout and view Id's .

Exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id

Comment: For a `Fragment` nested inside another `Fragment`, you should use `getChildFragmentManager()`, instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: The same code is working well on some devices which has Android 4.4.2 and other devices make an exception like Samsung Active Tab T365 which run on Android 5.1.1

Comment: I tried getChildFragmentManager() it but the same error